# How do I exclude parameters from an RDA plot

Tags: r, plot, rda

I'm still relatively inexperienced manipulating plots in R, and am in need of assistance. I ran a redundancy analysis in R using the `rda()` function, but now I need to simplify the figure to exclude unnecessary information. The code I'm currently using is:

```
abio1516<-read.csv("1516 descriptors.csv")
attach(abio1516)
bio1516<-read.csv("1516habund.csv")
attach(bio1516)
rda1516<-rda(bio1516[,2:18],abio1516[,2:6])

anova(rda1516)
RsquareAdj(rda1516)
summary(rda1516)

  varpart(bio1516[,2:18],~Distance_to_source,~Depth, ~Veg._cover, ~Surface_area,data=abio1516)
plot(rda1516,bty="n",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",main="1516; P=, R^2=",
     ylab="Driven by , Var explained=",xlab="Driven by , Var explained=")
```

The produced plot looks like this:
[image: rda plot]

Please help me modify my code to: exclude the sites (sit#), all axes, and the internal dashed lines.

I'd also like to either expand the size of the field, or move the vector labels to all fit in the plotting field.

**updated as per responses, working code below this point**

```
plot(rda,bty="n",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",type="n",main="xxx",ylab="xxx",xlab="xxx
Overall best:xxx")

abline(h=0,v=0,col="white",lwd=3)
points(rda,display="species",col="blue")
points(rda,display="cn",col="black")
text(rda,display="cn",col="black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by plotting the rda with `type = "n"` which generates an empty plot to which you can add the things you want. The dotted lines are hard coded into the plot.cca function, so you need either make your own version, or use `abline` to hide them (then use `box` to cover up the holes in the axes).

```
require(vegan)
data(dune, dune.env)
rda1516 <- rda(dune~., data = dune.env)

plot(rda1516, type = "n")
abline(h = 0, v = 0, col = "white", lwd = 3)
box()
points(rda1516, display = "species")
points(rda1516, display = "cn", col = "blue")
text(rda1516, display = "cn", col = "blue")
```

If the `text` labels are not in the correct position, you can use the argument `pos` to move them (make a vector as long as the number of arrows you have with the integers 1 - 4 to move the label down, left, up, or right. (there might be better solutions to this)

Comment: That's great thanks! It fixed the majority of my problems. The only one remaining is I cant seem to get rid of axis 3 or axis 4 (top and right).
I tried:
axis(4,labels=FALSE,tick="FALSE",col="white")
axis(3,labels=FALSE,tick="FALSE",col="white")
but it didn't work. 

any suggestions?

Comment: Those axes are needed for the scale of the arrows. Of course you could edit the code for `points.cca` and `text.cca` if you really don't want them.

Comment: Good point. I'll update the code above to help others in the future.